# Is there an easy way to give a MediaWiki wiki page a specific background colour?

Tags: colors, wiki, mediawiki

We're looking to give pages in a specific category a specific background colour.  Since every page in this category makes use of a specific template, we're ideally looking for a template change.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the MediaWiki 1.18, you only need [CSS](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aCSS) and this code:

```
{{#css:
    #bodyContent { background-color: yellow; }
  body {
    background: navajowhite;
  }
}}
```

This will give the part of the page with text a **yellow** colour and the rest (border) a **brown-ish** colour.

For best results, put this in a template, e.g. {{Page colour}}, so that it can be called with, e.g. {{Page color|red|yellow}}. The template code will then be:

```
{{#css:
    #bodyContent { background-color: {{{1|yellow}}}; }<!-- Page color -->
  body {
    background: {{{2|navajowhite}}};<!-- Border color -->
  }
}}
```

where 1 & 2 are parameters (page and border respectively) with default colours (yellow and brownish).

Answer (score 2):

Use the [PageCSS](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:PageCSS) extension, you should be able to put the css in your template, which would then apply to the pages it is on.

example:

```
 <css>
  #bodyContent { background-color: yellow; }
 </css>
```

Comment: This is a neat solution, thanks.  But on my installation it is not working (MW 1.13.2).  I'm checking to see why that is...

Comment: Slight change to the above code:
<css>
#mw_content{ background-color: yellow; }
</css>